# Order By problem with int Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have prices in a database as INT  if I order by I get

97,650

ends of appearing before

975,455

```
after sorting in DESC
```

It appears that since the 6 in the first price is greater than the 3rd place position in the second price, it counts that as a larger number.

Has anyone run into this problem and know how to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure the data is stored as numerical and not as text?

Comment: can you post the table definition and the query you're using?

Comment: It's definitely stores as a `VARCHAR`; it's default. Change it to `INT` and it should work fine.

Comment: L_AskingPrice  int(10)    Yes  NULL

Comment: It's definitely already an int

Comment: the commas here show only becuase I am doing a number money format with php after data is pulled and sorted

Comment: it's definitely not. You are lying to the community. What a shame

Comment: this question should be closed as too localized for being asked out of lie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test, try this slow and sad query.

```
select prices from (table) order by (prices+0);
```

If that query works, then it is likely your column is not an INT column. The `(prices+0)` makes certain that the data is treated as an integer.

Once you have found that this does indeed work for you, you need to alter the column to be an INT column.

Comment: @Adam that's definitely wrong answer. You should alter your table structure, not apply this ugly patch.

Comment: @Col, I have modified my answer to discourage such a patch

Comment: @adam, I agree with Col. S on this. This answer will really slow your queries down. Alter the table structure! It is not hard to do and you will be happier for it. (also, if your question is answered, please indicate that by checking the answer that you found most useful).

Comment: my problem is that I know for sure that the table field is set at an int(10)

Comment: no sorry sorry.  Here I am looking at the wrong table.  I apologize but thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  The table field was in fact a varchar!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the field type from `varchar` to `int`.