# MySQL Sorting when using FORMAT function

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

I have a query that **SUMS** different values and then orders the results using **ORDER BY**.

Whenever I format the result using **FORMAT** I get a different ordering than without format.

For example:

Ordering **without** format: 2827.0000, 1668.0000, 663.1000

Ordering **with** format: 663.10, 2,827.00, 1,668.00

What could be causing this behaviour?

This is the full query:

```
SELECT
FORMAT( ( (Sum(CASE WHEN YEAR(order_date) = 2015 THEN total END) / 100) - (SELECT COALESCE( ( SUM(total) / 100), 0) 
FROM returns WHERE customer = orders.customer AND YEAR(return_dat) = 2015) ), 2) AS anual

FROM orders

WHERE 1 GROUP BY customer ORDER BY anual DESC
```

Comment: Return order is never guaranteed unless you're performing an `ORDER BY`

Comment: I am using order by. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Show us the full query.

Comment: here it compares first digit of integer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5281027/4599982 hope it will add some value to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering formatted strings is going to result in ASCII-abetical sorting. If you want them sorted numerically, you'll need to have two columns, formatted and unformatted. Keep in mind this is usually best done in your application layer.